# CMake equivalent to -l as a gcc directive for ld to link to a library

Tags: gcc, linker, cmake, shared-libraries, ld

What is the equivalent to `-l` as a `gcc` directive for `ld` to link to a library in cmake?

For example, `g++ main.cpp -o myProgram -L./lib -lmyLib` , but for cmake?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The function you are looking for is [`target_link_libraries`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.12/cmake.html#command:target_link_libraries).

Your command line translates to the following CMake file:

```
project(myCMakeProject)
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)

link_directories(./lib)
add_executable(myProgram main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(myProgram myLib)
```

Note that in CMake it is unusual to hardcode link directories. Consider using [`find_library`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.12/cmake.html#command:find_library) or a [generated config file providing an imported target](http://www.cmake.org/Wiki/CMake/Tutorials/How_to_create_a_ProjectConfig.cmake_file) instead.